# column "expired_date" is of type date but expression is of type text

Tags: postgresql

I want update multiple row with multiple condition.

Here is my select query to test result.

```
select name, register_date, expired_date, to_char(register_date + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from tb_agent where agent_id = agent_id and agent_id in (46,47,62)
```

It can show result like I expected,

But when I craft to multiple update with this code

```
update tb_agent set expired_date = (select to_char(register_date + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from tb_agent where agent_id = agent_id) where agent_id in (46,47,62)
```

I got this

```
column "expired_date" is of type date but expression is of type text
```

register_date is date time column and expired_date is varchar

Is something wrong with my code?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You're casting `date` to `text` in `select`. Just remove `to_char()`.

Comment: @AlexM I need to format it as YYYY-MM-DD, question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_char` converts the date to a formatted string. you can cast it instead as a date.

but the update statement could be simplified to the following as well:

```
update tb_agent 
set expired_date = (register_date + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day')::date
where agent_id in (46,47,62)
```